# How are Volumetric Effects made within games? (e.g. Smoke/Fire)

Tags: textures, graphics

For computer generated volumetric elements such as clouds, fire, and whitewater.

How are they made? *Is it just a simple collection of particles [put to pixels] taken from Physics equations or are the like textures?*

How are they applied? I would assume not from UV mapping

---

[image]

Derbis, smoke and fire come from the vehicle.

Comment: related http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54871/what-is-billboarding-and-can-should-it-be-used-in-3d-games-to-create-special-ef

Comment: also related: [nVidia - GPU Gems 3](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/gpu-gems-3-chapter-30-real-time-simulation-and-rendering-3d-fluids)

Comment: @XGundam05 that is my answer - tells me absolutely everything how to render fluid phenomena and how to seamlessly integrate fluid rendering into an existing rasterization-based framework, as told. Including the physics. The only problem is that I dont understand Partial Differential Equations so I dont think Il ever get a chance to work on stuff like this :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Particle emitters with additive/multiplicative blending?

http://www.pxleyes.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/fumefx.jpg

Maybe you mean something different? But I think the effects in that screenshot is made out of particles with additive blending, and then overlayed with particles with multiplicative blending (the darker parts).